# Python 2.7. BeautifulSoup not opening HTML

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some weird problem with BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to read this website: http://lol.esportswikis.com/wiki/2015_International_Wild_Card_Invitational/Match_History and all I get is empty list. But if I try different site like: http://lol.esportswikis.com/wiki/Season_1_World_Championship/Match_History it works like a charm. Any idea whats the problem?

From chrome inspector tool I get the same code for 1st line of the table for both websites, so whats the problem?

```
    #mw-content-text > table.wikitable > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)
    mw-content-text > table.wikitable > tr #I use this
```

Even If I try to open just the wikitable

```
    url = 'insert url here'
    con = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    HTML = con.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'html.parser')
    stuff = soup.select('#mw-content-text > table.wikitable')
    print stuff
```

It just prints a empty list

Comment: This might be because what you're looking for is generated by JavaScript. `urlopen` doesn't execute JavaScript. Can you confirm that the HTML is actually in `soup` ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but command "print soup" prints the page source code properly and I don't think there is any JavaScript in the page, atleast not in the "wikitable" what I'm trying to open.

Comment: I just tried testing this myself. When using `html.parser` I get the result you describe. However, when using the `lxml` parser, it works as expected.

Comment: Brilliant! No I got the data that I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://lol.esportswikis.com/wiki/2015_International_Wild_Card_Invitational/Match_History')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'lxml')

row_text=[]
for row in soup.select('.wikitable tr')[2:]:
    print(row.get_text(' ',strip=True).replace(' • ','•'))
```

i don't have 2.7 env, so i use requests+bs4, but it's amost the same
i separate each cell by space in each row in case you want to split it

out:

```
2015-04-25 5.6 Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 36:54 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-25 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 53:47 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-25 5.6 Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 53:40 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-25 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 32:30 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 WarL0cK•007x•G4•Moss•Lloyd Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 45:53 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss 34:16 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 39:39 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko 36:58 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 32:03 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko 24:06 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-24 5.6 Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 38:01 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-23 5.6 BonziN•Astarore•Ceros•Yutapongo•KazuXD Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 32:01 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-23 5.6 WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss Swip3rR•Spookz•Swiffer•Raydere•Rosey 35:05 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-23 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster Helior•Juliostito•Regi•Zeicro•BearJew 18:40 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-23 5.6 Swip3rR•Spookz•Swiffer•Raydere•Rosey BonziN•Astarore•Ceros•Yutapongo•KazuXD 36:26 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-23 5.6 Helior•Juliostito•Regi•Zeicro•BearJew WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss 28:26 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 37:03 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 BonziN•Astarore•Ceros•Yutapongo•KazuXD Helior•Juliostito•Regi•Zeicro•BearJew 34:25 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko 40:49 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss 29:30 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko Swip3rR•Spookz•Swiffer•Raydere•Rosey 29:42 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 37:33 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 BonziN•Astarore•Ceros•Yutapongo•KazuXD WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss 27:38 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-22 5.6 Helior•Juliostito•Regi•Zeicro•BearJew Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko 38:38 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster BonziN•Astarore•Ceros•Yutapongo•KazuXD 35:52 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 Swip3rR•Spookz•Swiffer•Raydere•Rosey Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 44:25 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko 45:10 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge Helior•Juliostito•Regi•Zeicro•BearJew 35:51 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 Swip3rR•Spookz•Swiffer•Raydere•Rosey Yang•Revolta•Tockers•micaO•Jockster 43:21 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 WarL0cK•007x•G4•Lloyd•Moss Thaldrin•Theokoles•Energy•Nardeus•Dumbledoge 29:40 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 Smurf•Symphony•Kira•LeX•Dimonko BonziN•Astarore•Ceros•Yutapongo•KazuXD 30:17 k k - - - - - - SB - -
2015-04-21 5.6 Helior•Juliostito•Regi•Zeicro•BearJew Swip3rR•Spookz•Swiffer•Raydere•Rosey 43:52 63.3k 16 3 2 81.4k 22 11 3 -18.1k ▼ 18.1k -6 ▼ 6 -8 ▼ 8 -1 ▼ 1 - - SB - -
```